# How should I preg_match in correct format?

Tags: php, formatting, preg-match

I have preg_match problem. I should preg_match if xml text is something like this below.

```
<File label="asd 480p" type="lol" rate="1500" resolution="854x480">ValueIwant</File>
```

or this

```
<File label="720p" default="1">ValueIwant</File>
```

Now I'm using format like that

```
preg_match("'<File label=\"(?:720|576|cat|asd 480p).{1,50}>(.*?)</File>'si", $streamdata, $streamurl);
```

But it's working only for values like on my second example code < File label="720p" default="1">

Comment: [Regex is not the correct tool to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("'<File label=\"[(720)(576)(cat)(asd 480)].+>(.*)<\/File>'si", $streamdata, $streamurl);
```

The regex you posted should work too if you replace the {1,50} with either a higher number than 50 or just a plus sign (+).

Answer (score 0):

You are usually better off using an XML parser rather than preg_match to process XML. For example:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML( '<xml>
    <File label="asd 480p" type="lol" rate="1500" resolution="854x480">ValueIwant</File>
    <File label="720p" default="1">ValueIwant</File>
    </xml>' ); 

$searchNode = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "File" ); 

foreach( $searchNode as $searchNode ) {
    $label = $searchNode->getAttribute('label');

    $value = $searchNode->nodeValue;

    echo "$label - $value<br>";
}
```

Would output:

`asd 480p - ValueIwant
720p - ValueIwant`